# How to get the current line number of a file opened using Perl

Tags: perl, file

```
open my $fp, '<', $file or die $!;

while (<$fp>) {
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ /$regex/) {
        # How do I find out which line number this match happened at?
    }
}

close $fp;
```

Comment: If you want to read a line into $line, then read a line into $line rather than reading a line into some other variable and then copying it to $line:  while (my $line = <$fp>) {

Comment: @tadmc: or rather `while (defined( my $line = <$fp> )) { ... }`, since the last line could be a zero and not end in a newline.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `$.` (see [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)).

Comment: Very technically, `$.` isn’t necessarily the line number; it is the number of times that the `readline` operator has been called on the last handle it was called on since that handle’s last `close` (not `open`).  It would not reflect lines if `$/` is not set to `"\n"` (such as `""` or `"\n%%\n"`, or if the handle has had `open` called on it without a call to `close` (as occurs with `ARGV`, and thus with `<>`). And whether it is meaningful for text files with mangled last lines that don’t have a proper line termination sequence on them I leave for your own contemplation.

Comment: @tchrist: Your explanation of edge cases should have been posted as third answer here.

Comment: [perldoc eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof.html) recommends the `continue` part of `while(<>) { ... } continue { close ARGV if eof }` if using <>, addressing one of @tchrist's good caveats.

Answer (score 16):

You can also do it through an [OO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) interface:

```
use IO::Handle;

# later on ...
my $n = $fp->input_line_number();
```

This is in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), too.

Comment: That is subject to the same caveats as I just outlined for `$.`, of course.

Comment: Also note that the call is quite slow.  If you don't know where you are in a file and then you loop on the input, then store `$n` before the loop and `$n++` on each iteration instead of calling `$fp->input_line_number()` every time.

Answer (score -3):

[Here is explained why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20020550/4970442) we should avoid using `$.`, nor `$_` (or any global variable). Instead:

```perl
while(my $line = <FILE>) {
  print $line unless ${\*FILE}->input_line_number == 1;
}
```

To avoid this and a lot of others Perl gotchas, we can use text editors plugins/packages like [linter-perl](https://atom.io/packages/linter-perl). Due to these issues, some people believe Perl is [a write-only language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-only_language).