# Line number of a file in Perl when multiple files are passed as arguments to perl cli

Tags: perl

In `awk` if I give more than one file as an argument to `awk`, there are two special variables:

`NR`=line number corresponding to all the lines in all the files.

`FNR`=line number of the current file.

I know that in Perl, `$.` corresponds to `NR` (current line among lines in all of the files).

Is there anything comparable to `FNR` of AWK in Perl too?

Let's say I have some command line:

```
perl -pe 'print filename,<something special which hold the current file's line number>'  *.txt
```

This should give me output like:

```
file1.txt 1
file1.txt 2
file2.txt 1
```

Comment: print "File: ", __FILE__, " Line: ", __LINE__, "\n";  You should also check out http://www.catonmat.net/blog/perl-one-liners-explained-part-two/

Comment: Andy probably meant to name `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`, but forgot the code formatting.

Comment: Can you make the title more specific? It looks like a duplicate of e.g. *"[How to get the current line number of a file open using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920686/)"* (though its duplicate is probably somewhere else) - which it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such variable in Perl. But you should study [eof](http://p3rl.org/perlfunc#eof) to be able to write something like

```
perl -ne 'print join ":", $. + $sum, $., "\n"; $sum += $., $.=0  if eof;' *txt
```

Comment: @choroba : The answer to the OP's question is in the [eof](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#eof) documentation you linked!

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the [`eof`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#eof) documentation shows a way to do this:

```
# reset line numbering on each input file
while (<>) {
    next if /^\s*#/;  # skip comments
    print "$.\t$_";
} continue {
    close ARGV if eof;  # Not eof()!
}
```

An example one-liner that prints the first line of all files:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$ARGV : $_" if $. == 1; } continue { close ARGV if eof;' *txt
```

Comment: Isn't the last line missing a "{" and a "}"?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo_greeting explains what it is and how it works.

Comment: The one-liner is equivalent to: `perl -ne 'print "$ARGV : $_" if $. == 1; close ARGV if eof' *txt`. The `continue` block is no longer needed because there is no `next` instruction inside the main loop.

Answer (score 0):

I find this situation to be a very large drawback to using Perl.  While this answer is suboptimal, performance-wise, and only fits situations involving `xargs`, I've typically found it the workaround I use 95% of the time.  So the problem scenario:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 perl -ne 'print "$ARGV:$.\t$_" if /#define oom/'

file.h:85806    #define oom() exit(-1)
```

That line number is obviously not correct, and you'll obviously get the same behavior with `find`  Of course, with this regex, or other simpler Perl regexes, I'd just use `awk` or `git grep -P`.  However, if you're dealing with a fairly complicated regular expression, or need other Perl features, that won't work...and the *correct* answers to this question further complicate what is already likely to be a complicated Perl one-liner.

So I just use the following:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 perl -ne 'print "$ARGV:$.\t$_" if /#define oom/'

file.h:43       #define oom() exit(-1)
```

The `-n1` xargs argument causes xargs to kick off a Perl process for each file, which results in the correct line numbers.  You're looking at *very* significant performance impact, but I've found it acceptable for very large projects with millions of lines of code vs. solving it in Perl, which I find almost always requires an actual script vs. a one-liner.  It is *not* acceptable for system-wide searches in the vast majority of cases.