# Is __LINE__ constant-folded in this Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, constantfolding

In exploring an alternative answer to sarathi's [current file line number question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12384692/133939), I wrote this one-liner with the expectation that it would print the first line of all files provided:

```
$ perl -ne 'print "$ARGV : $_" if __LINE__ == 1;' *txt
```

This did not work as expected; all lines were printed.

Running the one-liner through `-MO=Deparse` shows that the conditional is not present. I assume this is because it has been constant-folded at compile time:

```
$  perl -MO=Deparse -ne 'print "$ARGV : $_" if __LINE__ == 1;' *txt
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    print "$ARGV : $_";
}
-e syntax OK
```

But why?

Run under Perl 5.8.8.

Comment: Check my edit for printing the first line of all the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__LINE__` corresponds to the line number in the Perl source, not in the input file.

Comment: I'm enjoying my 'Aha!' moment here. Should have read [`perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals) more carefully...

Answer (score 4):

`__LINE__` is the source line number i.e., the program line number.
`$.` will give you the input file line number.

if you want to print all the first lines of all the files then you can try this:

```
perl -lne '$.=0 if eof;print $_ if ($.==1)' *.txt
```

Comment: Yup! What muddled me up was the use of current file name and your problem's context